# Not able to convert image into base64 using java

Tags: java, base64

I want to convert image into `base64 String` using java.

I tried with following code

```
FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)imagePath.length()];
fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);

String encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

But it returns a very small string which is not an image.

Please look at base64 String that I am getting.

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABQAAAANVCAIAAACoFcTeAACAAElEQVR42nydBXQcR9a2Y0saZtAwg2AkzYhlWZaZGRKjmJkZLMnMIDPJFCeO7YDtOEbZlswQ2mR590t2s5hv4VtKNqT/Vt2e1tjZ/X3e06en1dNdXV09rqfeW7df2BTt2A==
```

Please help me .Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)imagePath.length()];
```

Here you get a byte array with length equals to your `imagePath.length`, which is a couple hundred of bytes at most (`imagePath` is `your/path/to/image.png`...)

Instead, you have to get all the bytes from `image` under `imagePath`:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(imagePath));
String encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

Comment: thhank you @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn you saved my time.